# Add an hour onto the time being transmitted via 'time1'=>urlencode($time1)

Tags: php, html, mysql, wordpress

I am a total novice at this kind of stuff, but if anyone could help me i would be eternally grateful.

I have a Wordpress Booking Calendar plugin that sends the booking details over to Google Calendar - this works fine apart from the time being sent over is 1 hour less, compared to the time actually booked. i.e. if booked at 9am, it would appear on Google Calendar at 8am.

I have pinpointed it to being this bit of code:

```
'time1'=>urlencode($time1)
```

I have tried many different solutions and have changed the booking time everywhere but where I actually want it.

The timezone on both Wordpress and Google Calendar matchup (and even when i change them to +1 on Wordpress - Google is still 1 hour out - the only thing that works is making Google Cal GMT-1, but then that messes everything else up) and the value of the $time1 appears correctly in the booking details in the Plugin details on Wordpress.

Just not sure how to add 1 hour, 3600 seconds or whatever to $time1 (as i say, i'm a complete novice) in this instance.

$time1 represents H:i details

Comment: Where is the old question? Has been asked several minutes before and already has been commented ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will add an hour to `$time1`, that being said this can probably be solved by tracing that variable and finding out why exactly it isn't right. If it's a well known plugin it is still easy to believe there is a configuration error on your site. But you've done your own debugging before asking this question though, which is very good.

```
'time1' => urlencode( date( 'H:i', strtotime( $time1 . ' +1 hour' ) ) )
```

Comment: That will add a little more than an hour. :P

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I get "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.'..." with this. Its not a well known plugin, and I have had many errors with it :(. It's just very frustrating. If it helps this is some more of the code... 
$fields = array(
'appointment_googleuser'=>urlencode($appointment_googleuser),
'appointment_googlepass'=>urlencode($appointment_googlepass),
'title'=>urlencode($nome),
'desc'=>urlencode($description),
'where'=>urlencode($nome),
'date1'=>urlencode($facia1),
'time1' => urlencode($time1),
'date2'=>urlencode($facia2),
'time2'=>urlencode($time2)
);

Comment: No sorry, the + wasn't supposed to be there. I updated the code.

Comment: Technically you can't use the `;` and the `=>` together. It's either `=` with `;` or `=>` with nothing, or a `,`.

Comment: A thousand thank you's! you have resolved hours of frustration. Thank you very much.

Comment: @h2ooooooo Yes of course, I'll correct that. It's obvious when you see it in an array, but when you write just the one line the habit kicks in to end it with ; lol. Glad it worked in the end.

Comment: @Calle I know you knew, I just wanted to make sure everyone else did as well. :-) Have a good weekend.